# Чем ng-container отличается от ng-template?

Tags: angular2, angular

Смотрел документацию и читал ответы на enSO и так и не понял, чем между ними разница...

Сначала у меня была такая разметка и ничего не отображалось:

```
<ng-template*ngIf="permissionService.canUpload()">
  <div>Загрузка новой версии</div>
  <hr />
  <app-uploader [showDependencyButton]="false" (uploadComplete)="reloadVersions()" [assemblyId]="assemblyId">
  </app-uploader>
</ng-template>
```

Потом поменял на такую и все стало норм:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="permissionService.canUpload()">
  <div>Загрузка новой версии</div>
  <hr />
  <app-uploader [showDependencyButton]="false" (uploadComplete)="reloadVersions()" [assemblyId]="assemblyId">
  </app-uploader>
</ng-container>
```

Или ng-template можно использовать только в условиях, что бы отрисовать тот или иной блок?

Comment: [Angular ng-template, ng-container and ngTemplateOutlet - The Complete Guide To Angular Templates](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Технические введение**

`ng-template` это не DOM элемент, в отличии от `ng-container`. Это низкоуровневая абстракция, которая компилируется в анонимный компонент внутри компонента, технически это называется "embedded view".

До выхода Angular 9 и до того как стабилизировался компилятор шаблонов Ivy, View Engine компилировал шаблон в структуру данных, которая называется "view definition" (определение представления).

Представим себе `AppComponent` с таким шаблоном:

```html
<button (click)="clickMe()">Нажми на меня!</button>
```

После компиляции мы получим view definition:

```
function View_AppComponent() {
  return viewDef(
    ViewFlags.OnPush,
    [
      elementDef(
        0,
        NodeFlags.None,
        null,
        null,
        1,
        'button',
        [],
        null,
        [[null, 'click']],
        ({ component }: ViewData, eventName: string) => {
          let preventDefault = true;
          if (eventName === 'click') {
            const result = component.clickMe() !== false;
            preventDefault = result && preventDefault;
          }
          return preventDefault;
        },
        null,
        null
      ),
      textDef(-1, null, ['Нажми на меня!']),
    ],
    null,
    null
  );
}
```

`function View_AppComponent` - это фабрика, которая возвращает "view definition", внутри называется `ViewDefinitionFactory`:

```
export interface DefinitionFactory<D extends Definition<any>> {
  (): D;
}

export interface Definition<DF extends DefinitionFactory<any>> {
  factory: DF | null;
}

export interface ViewDefinitionFactory
  extends DefinitionFactory<ViewDefinition> {}
```

Создается definition всего 1 раз и кешируется:

```js
const DEFINITION_CACHE = new WeakMap();
function resolveDefinition(factory) {
  let value = DEFINITION_CACHE.get(factory);
  if (!value) {
    // `value = View_AppComponent()`.
    value = factory();
    value.factory = factory;
    DEFINITION_CACHE.set(factory, value);
  }
  return value;
}
```

В будущем Angular использует эту структуру данных для создания компонента, а компонент представляет из себя не только шаблон. В шаблоне есть интерполяция, биндинги, директивы, в классе компонента есть конструктор с зависимостями. Компоновщик помогает Angular объединить шаблон и класс компонента в эту самую структуру данных.

В Ivy не используются эти структуры данных, там компилятор генерирует инструкции:

```js
AppComponent.ɵcmp = defineComponent({
  type: AppComponent,
  selectors: [['app-root']],
  decls: 2,
  vars: 0,
  consts: [[3, 'click']],
  template: function AppComponent_Template(rf: RenderFlags, ctx: AppComponent) {
    if (rf & RenderFlags.Create) {
      elementStart(0, 'button', 0);
      listener('click', () => ctx.clickMe());
      text(1, 'Нажми на меня!');
      elementEnd();
    }
  },
});
```

Когда Angular будет создавать компонент, то ему достаточно будет вызвать функцию `template(RenderFlags.Create, new AppComponent())`.

Сгенерированный Ivy код читабельнее и более понятен, в сравнении с View Engine.

Ментальная модель такого подхода похожа инстуркции языка ассемблера, внутри есть виртуальный стек, где Angular хранит текущую выполняемую `template` функцию:

```js
const instructionState = {
  lFrame: createLFrame(null),
  bindingsEnabled: true,
  isInCheckNoChangesMode: false,
};
```

Очень похоже на то, как процессор хранит адрес текущей выполняемой команды в регистре, под названием счетчик команд (PC). Angular может проверить пуст ли сейчас стек или нет через `instructionState.lFrame.parent === null`.

В дальнейшем мы будем ориентироваться на Ivy компилятор, потому что он проще, чем View Engine.

---

> т.е у меня в итоге получается ng-template внутри ng-template + внешний ng-template не имеет структурной директивы => не видимый?

Нет, инициализировать внутренности `ng-template` можно только руками (с помощью определенного кода), а сам `ng-template` на выходе станет фабрикой для создания анонимных компонентов (которые будут иметь идентичный DOM шаблон). Это в прямом смысле "шаблон", на основе которого, можно создавать представления внутри представления, потому и называется "embedded view":

```html
<ng-template>
  <p>Меня не видно :)</p>
</ng-template>
```

`ng-container` это DOM элемент, не имеющий селектора. Все DOM узлы в шаблонах (`p`, `div`, `span` и т.д.) раньше компилировались в "element definition" (представление элемента), это структура данных, которая похожа на view definition. Эта структура данных состояла из таких свойств, как `namespaceAndName`, `bindingCount`, `outputCount`, `nodes` и т.д. У параграфа свойство `namespaceAndName` равняется `p`, а вот у `ng-container` - `null`. Когда Angular итерировал definition's, дабы создать DOM элемент, он проверял чему равняется это свойство и создавал элемент или комментарий:

```js
if (elDef.name) {
  el = renderer.createElement(elDef.name, elDef.ns);
} else {
  el = renderer.createComment('');
}
```

В рантайме `ng-container` на самом деле является физическим узлом - комментарием, поэтому его внутренности видно:

```html
<ng-container>
  <p>А меня видно :)</p>
</ng-container>
```

На практике конечно в сам комментарий добавлять дочерние узлы нельзя:

```js
const comment = document.createComment('');
comment.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
// Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.
```

Поэтому, когда Angular создавал view definition, то он проверял какой элемент является родителем для добавления туда дочерних узлов:

```js
if (currentParent && isNgContainer(currentParent)) {
  currentRenderParent = currentParent.renderParent;
}
```

Когда `currentParent` будет ссылаться на `ng-container`, то Angular проверит `isNgContainer`, который вернет `true` и установит `currentRenderParent` в родительский `renderParent` (например `app-root`). Поэтому узлы, находящие в шаблоне внутри `ng-container`, в рантайме будут на одном уровне с ним:

```html
<app-root>
  <ng-container></ng-container>
  <p>А меня видно :)</p>
</app-root>
```

В Ivy шаблон компилируется в инстуркции и для всех DOM элементов генерируются 2 инструкции:

```js
elementStart(
  // индекс
  0,
  // название DOM элемента
  'button'
);
elementEnd();
```

`elementStart` создает DOM элемент внутри:

```js
const renderer = lView[RENDERER];
const native = renderer.createElement(name, getNamespace());
appendChild(tView, lView, native, tNode);
```

Для `ng-container` теперь генерируются отдельные инструкции:

```js
elementContainerStart(
  // индекс
  0
);
elementContainerEnd();
```

Там также внутри создается комментарий:

```js
const renderer = lView[RENDERER];
const native = renderer.createComment(ngDevMode ? 'ng-container' : '');
appendChild(tView, lView, native, tNode);
```

На этом теорию про `ng-container` можно закончить, важно помнить, что это просто DOM комментарий. Все, что находится внутри `ng-container` в шаблоне компонента, в рантайме будет распологаться ПОСЛЕ комментария.

---

Как говорилось ранее, `ng-template` - это анонимный компонент, его можно создавать динамически сколько угодно раз и передавать разный контекст. "Звездочку" можно использовать с чем угодно, кроме `ng-template`, потому что звездочка это синтаксический сахар, в скомпилированном коде структурных директив не существует, потому что структурные директивы - это те же атрибутые, только с привязкой к `ng-template`. Ибо это:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="permissionService.canUpload()">
  <div>Загрузка новой версии</div>
</ng-container>
```

Компилируется в это:

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="permissionService.canUpload()">
  <ng-container>
    <div>Загрузка новой версии</div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

При привязке к `ng-template` в конструктор директивы можно заинжектить `TemplateRef` и создать представление динамически.

Кстати, `TemplateRef` можно инжектить только в директивы, привязанные к `ng-template`. Например, в `AppComponent` это не сработает:

```
export class AppComponent {
  // Ошибка:  No provider for TemplateRef found.
  constructor(templateRef: TemplateRef<unknown>) {}
}
```

Пример структурной директивы, которая создает представление при следующем layout обновлении:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[rAF]' })
export class RequestAnimationFrameDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private requestId: number | null = null;

  constructor(
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<unknown>
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.requestId = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestId);
  }
}
```

Чтобы использовать эту директиву нам понадобится любой элемент и звездочка, либо `ng-template` + атрибутная привязка:

```html
<div *rAF>
  <p>Меня увидят при следующем обновлении layout!</p>
</div>

<ng-template [rAF]>
  <div>
    <p>Меня увидят при следующем обновлении layout!</p>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Два варианта полностью идентичны друг другу, поведение - одинаковое, скомпилированный код - одинаковый:

```js
function Ng_Template(rf, ctx) {
  if (rf & RenderFlags.Create) {
    elementStart(/* индекс */ 0, /* название DOM элемента */ 'div');
    elementStart(/* индекс */ 1, /* название DOM элемента */ 'p');
    text(
      /* индекс */ 2,
      /* сам текст */ 'Меня увидят при следующем обновлении layout!'
    );
    elementEnd();
    elementEnd();
  }
}

function Component_Template(rf, ctx) {
  if (rf & RenderFlags.Create) {
    template(
      // индекс
      0,
      // шаблонная функция анонимного компонента
      Ng_Template,
      // кол-во DOM узлов внутри анонимного компонента
      3,
      // кол-во биндингов внутри анонимного компонента
      0,
      // название тега, к которому происходит привязка
      'ng-template'
    );
  }
}
```

> Посмотреть скомпилированный код компонента можно в браузере через консоль: `ng.getComponent($('app-root')).constructor.ɵcmp.template.toString()` (работает только с Ivy). Либо же после `ng build` компиляции:

```js
// prettify.js

const fs = require('fs');
const prettier = require('prettier');
const stripComments = require('strip-comments');

const source = fs.readFileSync('./dist/main.js').toString();

fs.writeFileSync(
  './dist/main.js',
  prettier.format(stripComments(source), { parser: 'babel' })
);

// node prettify.js
```

Вопрос "использовать ли `ng-container` или нет" подобен вопросу "использовать ли `prettier` или нет", все ситуативно, каждая команда должна сама принимать решение для консистентности своей кодовой базы, чтобы не оказалось, что половина использует звездочку, а половина - атрибутный биндинг. Читабельнее ли со "звездочкой" или без - опять же вопрос субъективный, кому-то читабельнее, кому-то все равно :)

Я (лично) не использую `ng-container` вообще, у меня есть на то причины.

Используя `ng-template` + `ngIf` (как атрибутный биндинг) можно не прибегать к выделению памяти под:

- инструкции для создания `ng-container`
- DOM элемент в рантайме

На выходе мы имеем:

- меньше скомпилированного кода = меньше размер бандла
- меньше использованной памяти в рантайме
- меньше DOM узлов

Когда во всем DOM содержится 10, 20 или 30 комментариев - это не имеет значения. Бывали случаи на проекте когда в рантайме у нас было 13к DOM узлов, потом мы посчитали, что 4к из них были комментарии :) Композитный поток браузера старается уложить определенную часть работы в один фрейм, если не успевает, то что-то откладывает на следующий фрейм, если не может отложить, то происходит "frame drop".

---

Перейдем к примерам. `ngIf`:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="interval$ | async as counter">
  <p>{{ counter }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

Скомпилированный шаблон:

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="interval$ | async" let-counter>
  <ng-container>
    <p>{{ counter }}</p>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Без `ng-container`:

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="interval$ | async" let-counter>
  <p>{{ counter }}</p>
</ng-template>
```

`ngFor`:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
  <app-product
    *ngFor="let product of item.value"
    [product]="product"
  ></app-product>
</ng-container>
```

Скомпилированный шаблон:

```html
<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="object | keyvalue" let-item>
  <ng-container>
    <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="item.value" let-product>
      <app-product [product]="product"></app-product>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Без `ng-container`:

```html
<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="object | keyvalue" let-item>
  <app-product
    *ngFor="let product of item.value"
    [product]="product"
  ></app-product>
</ng-template>
```

`ngTemplateOutlet`:

```html
<ng-container
  *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: { $implicit: 500 }"
></ng-container>

<ng-template #template let-number>
  <p>{{ number }}</p>
</ng-template>
```

Скомпилированный шаблон:

```html
<ng-template
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: 500 }"
>
  <ng-container></ng-container>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #template let-number>
  <p>{{ number }}</p>
</ng-template>
```

Без `ng-container`:

```html
<ng-template
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: 500 }"
>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #template let-number>
  <p>{{ number }}</p>
</ng-template>
```

`ngComponentOutlet`:

```html
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="component; injector: injector"></ng-container>
```

Скомпилированный шаблон:

```html
<ng-template
  [ngComponentOutlet]="component"
  [ngComponentOutletInjector]="injector"
>
  <ng-container></ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Без `ng-container`:

```html
<ng-template
  [ngComponentOutlet]="component"
  [ngComponentOutletInjector]="injector"
>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: А имеет ли смысл использовать `ng-container` в случаях обертки `*ngFor` в `*ngIf`?

Comment: @Venta я же по-моему на это ответил :)