# Желателен ли ng-container для *ngIf

Tags: angular

Часто встречаю подобный код:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="someCondition">
  <some-component [smth]="smth"></some-component>
</ng-container>
```

Но ведь его можно записать проще:

```
<some-component *ngIf="someCondition" [smth]="smth"></some-component>
```

Если есть только один вложенный элемент, то есть ли какой-то скрытый смысл в использовании `ng-container`? Какой из вариантов лучше в плане производительности? Или они вообще полностью эквивалентны?

Comment: в конечной разметке есть див соответствующий ng-container?

Comment: @Grundy, в какой ещё разметке? о_О

Comment: в конечной же :-) когда все отрендерилось :)

Comment: Это что-то типа операторных скобок, или оператора группировки внутренних элементов. Смысл именно в том, чтобы применить некое действие к нескольким элементам сразу, то есть к группе внутренних элементов. В DOM никак не заносится :) Ну, в данном примере, как часто и бывает просто логическое разделение для удобочитаемости, чтобы не засорять some-component "не его" входными параметрами (инпутами)

Comment: и не делать лишний de-sugar. Короче, такое

Comment: @Grundy, но ведь `ng-container` для того и нужен, чтобы в dom не было никакого контейнера. А во-вторых, разве я говорил, что условие истинно?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, но помимо конечной одинаковой вёрстки есть скомпилированный код, который её создаёт, а он может быть разным. Я его производительность имел в виду.

Comment: Я думаю, что код будет одинаковым, потому что второе разворачивается в первое. Но надо, конечно, убедиться

Comment: 1) Второе не разворачивается в первое. 2) > `то есть ли какой-то скрытый смысл в использовании ng-container` - нет. 3) > `Какой из вариантов лучше в плане производительности?` - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/989805/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-ng-container-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-ng-template/990087#990087

Comment: В плане производительности разница между этими двумя подходами незначительна. <ng-container> не создаёт дополнительных DOM-элементов, поэтому его использование не влияет на производительность. Основная цель <ng-container> - предоставить дополнительную гибкость в шаблоне без воздействия на DOM дерево.